# ILOG CPLEX: x2 > x1 (integer constraint)

Tags: cplex

I'm trying to construct a integer program that has a solution of x2 > x1 when x3 = 1, however cplex seems do something odd with the constraint c1 (x2 - x1 + 99 x3 > -99), perhaps it's a rounding error. Is there a different syntax that I can use to express c1 (x2 - x1 + 99 x3 > -99) to get the desired result?
Thanks

Problem File

```
Maximize
 obj: x1 + x2
Subject To
 c1: x2 - x1 + 99 x3 > -99
 c3: x3 = 1
Bounds
 1 <= x1 <= 2
 1 <= x2 <= 2
Binary
 x3
General
 x1
 x2
```

Cplex Solution

```
MIP - Integer optimal solution:  Objective =  4.0000000000e+00
Solution time =    0.00 sec.  Iterations = 0  Nodes = 0
Deterministic time = 0.00 ticks  (1.11 ticks/sec)

CPLEX> Incumbent solution
Variable Name           Solution Value
x1                            2.000000
x2                            2.000000
```

Comment: It is not about formatting. The constraint you have is trivially satisfied for any value of (x1,x2) in (1,2). Try this constraint instead: `c1: x2 - x1 - 99x3 > -98.999`  (RHS is -99 plus epsilon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be no "strictly greater than" constraint in CPLEX. Hence, CPLEX interprets what you provide as "greater than or equal to". Try

```
x2 - x1 + 99 x3 >= -98.99999999
```

P.S: Default precision for CPLEX is 8 digits.